# Corrupt when using Google Play Services Face Detection in Picasso Transformation. (Fatal Signal)

Tags: google-play-services, picasso

I'm writing a face crop transformation of Picasso. 
This is to make the face in image would be shown completely when Picasso cropping an image. 
So I implement a Picasso Transformation and using Face Detection in the function `public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source)`.

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;
....
public class FaceCrop implements Transformation {
    ...
    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        FaceDetector mFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(mContext).setTrackingEnabled(false).build();
        if (!mFaceDetector.isOperational()) {
            return source;
        }
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(source).build();
        SparseArray<Face> faces = mFaceDetector.detect(frame); // sometimes crash here
        ...
        RectF rect = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            Face face = faces.valueAt(i);
            float x = face.getPosition().x;
            float y = face.getPosition().y;
            RectF faceRect = new RectF(x, y, x + face.getWidth(), y + face.getHeight());
            if (rect == null) {
                rect = faceRect;
                continue;
            }
            rect.union(faceRect);
        }
        mFaceDetector.release();
        ...

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, source.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);
        source.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

For most images, it works perfectly. Nothing wrong. 
But for some specific images, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it crashes at `SparseArray<Face> faces = mFaceDetector.detect(frame);`. (it's not always crash for one image.)
I tried to use `try` and `catch` block to catch this error, it still crash anyway. So I can't skip it.
And the error messages are different every time, but they are similar.
They are all like "Fatal signal x (SIGABRT)...".
Here are 4 examples :
1. 
invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xba362ba0 passed to dlfree
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 10651 (Picasso-/extern)
2.
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x93948000 in tid 16443 (Picasso-/extern)
3.
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x605f5e6a in tid 17951 (GCDaemon)
4.
heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large
Fatal signal 6 (SIGSEGV), code -6 in tid 19020 (Picasso-/extern)


I am sure the parameter `frame` of function `detect` is not null.
I checked those images which sometimes cause the crash, I can't see anything wrong with them.
They looks normal, and they are not very large files (smaller than 1M). 
Some with faces, some are not.
And they all can be decoded normally by Picasso with Picasso's center crop.

Can anyone give me some suggestion? 
Thank you so much!!

Comment: According to the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector), there is an alternative method that you can try to use `a pipeline structure`. Take look at that code. Note that the face detector can be run with fairly low resolution images (e.g., 320x240).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing a same problem!

Comment: Sorry~ not yet! The google engineer 'pm0733464' is checking this problem. (See the comments of the 0 point answer in this page. ) But I don't know when  will he get an answer. I'm also still waiting his answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with small images, and this will be fixed in a future release.  But fortunately, there is a patch available on GitHub now:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/26

If you are still getting this issue even with that patch, please print out some of the image sizes and post here to help us to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But I still get this issue with that patch.
I put my test code(FaceCrop.java) and the image that can easily reproduce my issue in google drive.<br>
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3t1ypLfwUMDZ0VsY0E3M2QxWms&usp=sharing
<br>
And this is how I use the FaceCrop.java I write.
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.color.light_gray)
            .transform(new FaceCrop(0, 0, getContext())) // number value doesn't matter<br>
            .into(mPhotos);

Comment: Thanks.  We'll take a look.

Comment: I tried this image with the photo-demo app on GitHub, but I didn't see the crash that you are seeing.  Can you try it with that app as well:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/photo-demo.  What device are you running this on?

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the photo-demo app and replace the face.jpg to the image I gave you before. And I can see the crash~
I use two HTC Desire Eye devices, both can reproduce the crash.
I put the app and the apk file(actually the same with photo-demo just with different jpg image), and a video that show how I make it crash in google drive. Thank you again!!
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3t1ypLfwUMDenF6UG8tQkszNTg&usp=sharing

Comment: ASUS zenfone4 can also reproduce this issue with the steps I show in the video. Thank you!

Comment: OK.  We'll take a look.

Comment: What version of Android are you running with?

Comment: HTC Desire Eye Android version is 5.0.2. 
ASUS zonfone4 android version is 4.3